# Como usar o Dynamic Links com o domínio <projectID>.web.app?

Tags: firebase, hospedagem

Tenho uma aplicação hospedada usando um subdomínio do serviço de Hosting, essa aplicação também usa o Dynamic Links

É possível usar um caminho, por exemplo, `/share/<link>` no mesmo domínio da aplicação? (Essa rota não possui nenhum arquivo na aplicação)

Tentei configurando o arquivo angular.json:

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "appAssociation": "AUTO",
        "rewrites": [{
            "source": "/e/**",
            "dynamicLinks": true
        }, {
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
        }],

        // [...]
    }
}
```

Porém, ao tentar adicionar um novo prefixo de URL com o domínio da aplicação, requer que eu faça uma configuração que não sei como proceder:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível fazer isso? Como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> É possível fazer isso?

**Não**, o Firebase insiste que você use **<*meu site*>.page.link** para Dynamic Links.

Agora, se você conecta um domínio externo, aquela regra com `dynamicLinks` no `firebase.json` funciona perfeitamente.

> É possível usar um caminho, por exemplo, `/share/<link>` no mesmo
>   domínio da aplicação?

Então a resposta é **sim** para domínios conectados, e **não** para **<*meu site*>.web.app**.

Comment: @Costamilam Não é só ao <_projectId_>.web.app que abrange a resposta, mas a qualquer site adicional vindo de **web.app**. Pois você pode ter vários sites num mesmo projeto.

Comment: Verdade, e, no caso do page.link, nem é o id. Melhor reverter a edição